# Push pull product page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good morning, today's goal is creating a responsive ecommerce "detail" page with Bootstrap framework (v 3.0.3).

This is what we managed to do til now:

**MOBILE VERSION**

[image: MOBILE]

**DESKTOP VERSION**

[image]

My code, omitting the standard template:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 blocco rosso columns">LOGO</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 blocco verde columns">RICERCA</div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 blocco rosso columns">TITOLO</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 blocco alto blu columns">IMG</div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 blocco rosa columns">PREZZI</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 blocco arancio columns">AGGIUNGI</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 blocco giallo columns">DETTAGLI</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

I need the PREZZI; AGGIUNGI; DETTAGLI divs to be aligned below TITOLO: the line shouldn't be wrapped.

I mean TITOLO+PREZZI+AGGIUNGI+DETTAGLI should be a sidebar in desktop version while keeping the push/pull TITOLO/IMG behavior.

Can I do that using Bootstrap pure grid logic or am I forced to fix it with some CSS custom media query tricks?

Thx

Comment: make a fiddle http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can control the height of "titolo" block, checkout this fiddle: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/554jL/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 columns">LOGO</div> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 columns">RICERCA</div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 columns">TITOLO</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 alto columns">IMG</div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 columns siderbar">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 columns">PREZZI</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 columns">AGGIUNGI</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 columns">DETTAGLI</div>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>

.columns{
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.alto{
    min-height: 400px;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .siderbar{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is good, I already thought about that kind of solution but... I specified I'm looking for a "trick-free" solution, using bare rows and columns, push/pulls, and so on.. Thank you however...